# macOS Swift: Always show window tabbar programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, tabs, tabbar

Can anybody tell me how I can get my `NSWindow` to show the `TabBar` (incl. the "+"-Button), even if I have only one tab?

I know there is a Menu Option called "Show Tab Bar" that will lead to the tab bar showing even if you have only one tab. How can I get this functionality programmatically?

[See this example of a window showing the tab bar with only one tab open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce0hX.png)

Comment: What else do you need besides NSButton?

Comment: optimally, i want the whole tab bar... jsut as if i had two tabs or more, but i also want the tabbar for one tab

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is a bit late :) but still might help somebody.

Here is a solution for **SwiftUI** application:

1. To get the right instance of `NSWindow` you can check one of these answers:

- [How to access own window within SwiftUI view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359808/how-to-access-own-window-within-swiftui-view)
- [How to access NSWindow from @main App using only SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432700/how-to-access-nswindow-from-main-app-using-only-swiftui)

So in the end you will end up with something like this:

```swift
var window: NSWindow?
```

2. Add `.onAppear` modifier with the following code to your high level view in the app:

```swift
.onAppear {
    guard let window = window else { return }
    guard let tabGroup = window.tabGroup else { return }
    guard !tabGroup.isTabBarVisible else { return }
    window.toggleTabBar(.none)
}
```

It will trigger the same action as `Show Tab Bar` from `Menu -> View`