# How to change the theme color with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, swiftui-navigationlink

I need to change the title of all the `navigationlink`s to a different color other than blue, like a custom green. Don't know where to begin.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBfcC.png)

Comment: @ThomasMartin not quite. But I'll see if I can adapt it for `navigationlink` to my project. I'll report back if I do.

Answer (score 4):

Use accent color like the following

[image: demo]

```
NavigationView {
    // content here
}.accentColor(Color.green)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to declare this value once to take effect across the app?

Comment: @Scotty, accentColor is applied for all subviews, so just apply it for `ContentView` in `SceneDelegate` or use there `tintColor` applied directly to `UIWindow`. Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381525/12299030) topic.

Comment: I'm getting an error at `@Environment(\.hostingWindow) var hostingWindow`. Error reads `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

Comment: @Scotty, have you set up `hostingWindow` as specified by the link provided at the top of that answer?

Comment: I've tried piecing the different answers you've given on the topic and no luck.

Comment: Could you host your demo from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60368765/how-to-change-tintcolor-of-whole-app-swiftui?answertab=active#tab-top on github?

Comment: @Scotty, hosted - find link in that post.