# Is it possible to change the tint color of an alert in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

Hey I would like to change the tint color of an alert in SwiftUI, i tried .accentColor(.red) but it is not working.

Comment: Consider possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381525/12299030)