# SwiftUI: How can I change the Color of Alert Button and NavigationLink back button?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I change the Color from the Button in a Alert and the back Button from NavigationLink? To set `.accentColor(.init("someColor"))` after the Text from the Alert Button doesn't work. To set `.accentColor(.init("someColor"))` after navigationLink does not work too. What can I do?

The Alert Button:
[image]

The Back Button from NavigationLink:
[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showSheet = false
    @State var alertShouldBeShown = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "£Start")

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:  {
            self.showSheet.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("click me")
            //.accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Image("") : Image("Info-Icon"))
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView(showSheet: self.$showSheet)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $alertShouldBeShown, content: {

            Alert(title: Text("Headline"),
                message: Text("Text"),
                dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(
                    Text("Ok"), action: {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Start")
                    }
                )
            )
        })
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            DetailView()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Headline"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.showSheet = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done")
                        .bold()
            })
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewOne()) {
                                    Text("View 1")
                }
            }
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewTwo()) {
                                    Text("View 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailViewOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("1")
    }
}

struct DetailViewTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("2")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381525/12299030?

Comment: No this solution doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the NavigationBar accent color by using `accentColor` but you need to apply it to the `SheetView` (the root view of a given environment):

```
SheetView(showSheet: self.$showSheet)
    .accentColor(.red)
```

---

Unfortunately SwiftUI doesn't allow much of `Alert` customisation so far.

However, as `Alert` is built on top of UIKit components (`UIAlertController`) this also means you can change the *appearance* of `UIView` when contained in `UIAlertController`.

You can put this code in your @main App init or in the SceneDelegate:

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = .red
```

Comment: Nice, a one-liner fix that applies to all UIKit and SwiftUI Alerts.

Answer (score 2):

I would caution against calling `UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor` in @main App init or in the SceneDelegate as this will change the tintColor for all Alerts in the app. To change the tintColor of a specific Alert, add this ViewModifier and extension to View:

```
extension View {
    func alertButtonTint(color: Color) -> some View {
        modifier(AlertButtonTintColor(color: color))
    }
}

struct AlertButtonTintColor: ViewModifier {
    let color: Color
    @State private var previousTintColor: UIColor?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                previousTintColor = UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor
                UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = UIColor(color)
            }
            .onDisappear {
                UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = previousTintColor
            }
    }
}
```

This will change the button tintColor on the specific alert and not change all tintColors globally.

Usage:

```
struct AlertTest: View {
@State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert", action: { showAlert = true })
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Alert Title"),
                      message: Text("Alert message"),
                      dismissButton: .default(Text("Reset Value"), action: { print("OK!!!") }))
            }
            .alertButtonTint(color: .orange)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: alertImage]