# swiftUI detects app state moves to foreground from background

Tags: swiftui, background-foreground

I have below logic which give app state:
But i wanted to add logic when app move to foreground.

In Swift we have method. I am looking for something similar method in swiftui

```
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {

 

but in Swiftui i only have .active, .inactive and .background


     .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                if newPhase == .active {
                    
                } else if newPhase == .inactive {
                    
                } else if newPhase == .background {
                    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `.onReceive` with subscription to Notification Center publisher on `UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification` notification, or, after all, mentioned scene delegate callback (having scene delegate as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359809/12299030)