# How to change the background behind the stack of sheets in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

How can I change the background here (black) to another color? I was playing around with an app called Honk, and they've set different backgrounds in some of their sections. I saw something on SO that said it could be done with `window.backgroundColor = .magenta` but I have no idea where to put that. I assumed it would either be inside the `init()` or as a property on the highest-level view of my app ie `NavigationView`, but no luck so far.

[image]

Here's a screenshot from Honk for reference:

[image]

And another:

[image]

Comment: This should be helpful [How to access own window within SwiftUI view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359809/12299030)

Answer (score 1):

You can do somethings like this, it worked for me.
Use the on appear modifier and call the function setWindowBackgroundColor and pass the color you want the background behind the stack to be.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isSheetPresented = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            isSheetPresented = true
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
        SheetView()
            .onAppear {
                setWindowBackgroundColor(.black) // Set the background color behind the sheet
            }
            .onDisappear {
                setWindowBackgroundColor(.white) // Reset the background color when the sheet is dismissed
            }
    }
}

private func setWindowBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor) {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
}

struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sheet Content")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much (and sorry to only see it now). This is exactly what I was looking for. Just a heads up, when I added that function, I got a build warning that says: `'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead`

Is this something that would be blocked by review? How would we make this error go away? FWIW I tried ChatGPT for this, and it couldn't figure out a solution that worked (kept giving me broken code).

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 17.

Comment: @ragavanmonke and anyone else wondering how to get around the warning:

```swift
let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
windowScene?.windows.first?.backgroundColor = color
```

Answer (score 1):

As people have rightly pointed out in the comments of the accepted answer that it has become slightly outdated in iOS 17. I just changed the reply by @BFeher to not need as much optional chaining in the function:

```swift
private func setWindowBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor) {
    if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
        let window = windowScene.windows.first
    {
        window.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```