# SwiftUI macos NSWindow instance

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nswindow

Using Xcode 12.3 and Swift 5.3 with the SwiftUI App lifecycle to build a macOS application, what is the best way to access and change the appearance and behaviour of the `NSWindow`?

**Edit:** What I'm really after is the `NSWindow` instance.

I've added an `AppDelegate`, but as I understand it the `NSWindow` is likely to be `nil`, so unavailable for modification, and simply creating one here similar to the AppKit App Delegate lifecycle method results in two windows appearing at launch.

One solution would be preventing the default window from appearing, and leaving it all to the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method, but not sure this is possible or sensible.

The `WindowStyle` protocol looks to be a possible solution, but not sure how best to leverage that with a `CustomWindowStyle` at this stage, and whether that provides access to the `NSWindow` instance for fine-grained control.

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {        
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
      // In AppKit simply create the NSWindow and modify style.
      // In SwiftUI creating an NSWindow and styling results in 2 windows, 
      // one styled and the other default.
    }
}

@main
struct testApp: App {
    
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate : AppDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assign an NSAppearance to it? See e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I don't think an NSAppearance will be sufficient to cover my use case as I need to control other aspects of the NSWindow's behaviour. I'll edit my question to make this requirement a bit more obvious.

Comment: Trying to do the same thing right now. Severe lack of know how on this on Google. The conforming types here don't seem to work for me either - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowstyle

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that there would be a bit more relating to the conforming types and how to achieve similar by implementing the  `WindowStyle` protocol, but haven't been able to find anything yet, although I have been able to use those defined in the documentation, i.e. `HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle` worked well-enough, but I'd need my own implementation to achieve what I'm after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although I am not entirely sure this is exactly the right approach, based on the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439982/792406 I have been able to access the `NSWindow` instance and modify its appearance.

For quick reference, here's a working example based on the original code provided by [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) using `xcode 12.3`, `swift 5.3`, and the SwiftUI App Life cycle.

```swift
@main
struct testApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class Store {
    var window: NSWindow
    
    init(window: NSWindow) {
        self.window = window
        self.window.isOpaque = false
        self.window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var window: NSWindow?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Loading...")
            if nil != window {
                MainView(store: Store(window: window!))
            }
        }.background(WindowAccessor(window: $window))
    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    let store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("MainView with Window: \(store.window)")
        }.frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
}

struct WindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var window: NSWindow?
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = view.window
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: hey hillmark I like this answer, but no questing, what if I want to replace the ContentView with some other view, without opening another NSWindow

Answer (score 13):

Interesting approach @hillmark.

I also got it working with an approach using `NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor`.

I believe the code below would only help you with a single window MacOS SwiftUI application - a multi window app would likely need to handle all the windows, rather than just take the first one.

I'm also not sure of any caveats of my approach yet.

For now this solves my issue precisely, but I'll check your approach out also.

```
import SwiftUI

final class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
            window.titleVisibility = .hidden
            window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            window.isOpaque = false
            window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        }
    }
}

@main
struct AlreadyMacOSApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NewLayoutTest()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm on the multi-window path and am now finding that the hosting window approach is providing me with flexibility to have different styles per window etc. with good separation. My appDelegate is slowly emptying out, which I'm viewing positively. Effectively, I'm ending up with a kind of container-type pattern similar to react.

Comment: Tried your approach. Works great, I've moved to that.

Comment: I'd be happy enough to see you answer your own question on this one.

Comment: couldn't it be made to work with multiple windows, if `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is replaced with `applicationWillUpdate` or `applicationDidUpdate`, and if you iterate over all (or some) windows instead of only on the first window?