# Is there a way to quit an app without force quitting on Mac Catalyst using the .sheet modifier?

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

Whenever I use the `.sheet` modifier on my Mac Catalyst/SwiftUI-based app, the red cross button is disabled and the only way to quit the app is to force quit it.

Is there any workaround to enable the red cross button even if the app is presenting a sheet?

[image: Screenshot illustrating red cross button disabled]

Comment: This problem also exists in UIKit-based Mac Catalyst apps that present a view controller as a form sheet or page sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to force quit.

**Option 1**

Present a `Quit` button on your sheet and handle closing your app.

**Option 2**

`NSWindow` has a property [`preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419743-preventsapplicationterminationwh). SwiftUI's sheet has an underlying `NSView` that we can access with @Asperi's [`WindowAccessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439982/16157878). This will enable to close the app with cmd + Q or from the menu.

Here is an example:

```
import SwiftUI

// This is the view to put in your `.sheet(..) modifier
struct Sheet: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    @State private var window: NSWindow?
#endif
    
    var body: some View {
        // conditionally apply the window accessor
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        SheetContent()
        // access the window
            .background(WindowAccessor(window: self.$window))
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
                    if let window = self.window {
                        // for other tricks you can connect to NSWindowDelegate here:
                        // window.delegate = appDelegate
                        // >> we're there: allow termination: <<
                        window.preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal = false
                    }
                }
            }
#else
        SheetContent()
#endif
    }
}
```

In my example, `SheetContent` is the actual content of that sheet:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetContent: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("I'm a modal!")
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture { dismiss() }
    }
}
```

Here's the `WindowAccessor`:

```
import SwiftUI

#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
struct WindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var window: NSWindow?
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = view.window
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
#endif
```

I'm sure the macCatalyst conditional code could be done more elegant.

This solution for sheets works the same also for Cocoa and SwiftUI lifecycles.

Comment: my first version was for macOS, I edited my solution with `macCatalyst`conditional code, so it will also build for iOS.

Comment: The code in Option 2 doesn't compile, I have this error (among others): `'NSWindow' is unavailable in Mac Catalyst`.
Regarding the Option 1 with the Quit button, this is the solution I've come up with, by calling `exit(0)` when the button is tapped, and so far it has passed the App Store review but I'm not quite comfortable with using such code.