# .onReceive NSWindow.willCloseNotification called for every window in App?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsnotificationcenter

I'm writing a multi-platform app in SwiftUI.

It handles 3 different kinds of windows, and as many instances of each as the user wants to open.

I need to do some cleanup when the user closes a window, so I added the following to the top-level View in my View hierarchy (a `NavigationStack` in this case)

```
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.willCloseNotification)) { newValue in
        // Do cleanup
    }
```

My expectation is that the closure for my  `.onReceive` handler would be called when the specific window that contains this specific View object is closed.

If you look up the `NSWindow.willCloseNotification` in AppKit, it says that it sends the notification to the specific window object that is about to be closed.

However, it seems that in SwiftUI, it gets called on every window when any window is about to be closed.

Why is that, and is there some trick to getting a notification when a **specific** instance of NSWindow is about to be closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you look up the `NSWindow.willCloseNotification` in AppKit, it says that it sends the notification to the specific window object that is about to be closed.

I believe that there might be a misunderstanding here of what the documentation is trying to express. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419400-willclosenotification):

> The notification object is the `NSWindow` object that’s about to close. This notification doesn’t contain a `userInfo` dictionary.

"The notification object" here refers to [`Notification.object`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notification/1779839-object), which is a generic property (general, not in the `<T>` sense) that describes an object which the notification is relevant to. Some notifications are global and not related to a specific object (in which case it can be `nil`), while others are indicating a change relevant to a specific object, in which case this will be set.

In this specific case, the `object` property of a `Notification` received for `NSWindow.willCloseNotification` is documented to be the window which will be closing, so that you can distinguish between windows which can close.

`Notification.object` isn't just relevant information when receiving notifications, though: you can use a specific object as a *filter* for notifications to receive when subscribing to notifications. Both [`NotificationCenter.addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver) and [`NotificationCenter.addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver) allow you to pass an `object` parameter in such that only notifications whose `.object` matches the given object are delivered — i.e., in case you only care about receiving `NSWindow.willCloseNotification` for a *specific* window object, you can pass it in up-front and notifications will only be delivered when `.object` matches.

Crucially, [`NotificationCenter.publisher(for:object:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/3329353-publisher) *also* allows you to pass in an `object` to filter for — it just happens to default to `nil` (which means that no filter is applied). The net effect of subscribing for notifications with no object is that each window which subscribes will receive notifications for *any* window that closes; i.e., exactly what you're seeing.

If you want each view hierarchy to be informed *only* when its *containing* window is about to close, you'll need to provide a reference to the containing `NSWindow` to `publisher(for:object:)`:

- If you're presenting SwiftUI using `NSHostingController`/`NSHostingView`, the easiest way to do this would be to grab a reference to the presenting window at `NSHosting*` creation time, then pass that in to your SwiftUI hierarchy
- If you're using the SwiftUI `App` lifecycle then accessing the AppKit world is likely easiest through `NSViewRepresentable` — it's possible to inject an empty `NSView` into your hierarchy whose sole purpose is to provide a reference to its `NSWindow`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439982/169394

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense that the notification Object is how window notifications are filtered. That begs the question, though. How do I find my owning window in a View object? You say "... you'll presumably need to pass in a reference when your top-level view is created." How?

Comment: @DuncanC Ah, sorry — I should have asked rather than assumed: are you embedding SwiftUI within an AppKit app, or are you using SwiftUI exclusively with the app lifecycle? My comment was directed at the former (e.g., if you've got SwiftUI presented in a hosting controller, at the layer where you create the hosting controller, you should have access to the presenting window), but it sounds like your situation is more likely the latter. If so, you might need to use something (unfortunately hacky) like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439982/169394

Comment: (I've updated the answer to be more explicit about this)

Comment: My app is pure SwiftUI. (Well, I am using an introspection library that lets me reach into the AppKit/UIKit objects to tweak them, but it's not SwiftUI in a hosting controller.)

Comment: I guess I need to open a new question asking how to gain access to a view's owning NSWindow/UIWindow so that I can use the window as the object for my `.onReceive`, unless you have a solution to suggest.

Comment: @DuncanC Does the linked SO answer not work in your case? (I would expect it to work for both AppKit and UIKit pretty identically, just swapping out `NS` ↔︎ `UI`)

Comment: I missed that addition to your answer. I'll have to try injecting an empty NSView/UIView. How would I then use that in order to have my .onReceive target my window though?

Comment: @DuncanC You would create a `@State` var in your containing view to hold a reference to the window, then pass a binding to it to your injected view (`WindowAccessor` in the example) — that injected view could then write to your variable, at which point you can pass that reference in to `onReceive`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256930/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-itai-ferber).